# ¿Cómo recorrer un conjunto de documentos de MongoDB en C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Tengo el siguiente codigo que obtiene todos los `documentos` que cumplan con el valor de campo que le  proporcione, el problema es que no encuentro la forma de "iterar" los elementos que contiene la consulta a la base de datos.

```
public void searchBy(string campo, string valor)
    {
        var collection_ = dataLocal.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("coleccion");
        var filtro = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(campo, valor);
        var documents = collection_.Find<BsonDocument>(filtro);
        //Recorrer documentos individualmente
    }
```

Comment: que driver estas usando?

Comment: Tengo MongoDB.Driver, MongoDB.Driver.GridFS, MongoDB.Driver.Core y MongoDB.Bson

Comment: esas son las DLLs pero si te vas a propiedades ahi te pone el nombre del driver en descripción

Comment: No se en que parte de propiedades se ve el driver. No entiendo del todo a que te refieres con driver.

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que en la base de datos `local` tenemos una `coleccion` de documentos como este:

```
{
    "item" : {
        "id" : "1",
        "desc" : "hey"
    }
}
```

Con el Official Driver puedes hacer esto:

```
var client = new MongoClient();
var dataLocal = client.GetDatabase("local");

string campo = "item.id";
string valor = "1";
var collection_ = dataLocal.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("coleccion");
var filtro = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(c=>c[campo], valor);
var documents = collection_.Find<BsonDocument>(filtro).ToList();

foreach(var document in documents)
{
    string hey = document["item"]["desc"].ToString();
}
```

Si todos los documentos van a ser iguales en estructura entonces te conviene crearte una clase en lugar de trabajar con BsonDocument.